# mssql_fetch_assoc not outputting (but vardump shows data)

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server

I have a very odd situation where my while loop 'sometimes' works and 'sometimes' not, but I can't find a common denominator.  I am basically pulling an array from a stored procedure in PHP, something I have done numerous times before.

First off, I have this:

```
$rowpayments = mssql_fetch_assoc($rspayreview);
 echo '<!-- DEBUG '; var_dump($rowpayments); echo ' -->';
```

This particular code DOES output the array in EVERY instance.

But when I attempt to `while` through the results and output them, sometimes the loop doesn't get to the debug code.

```
while($payinfo = mssql_fetch_assoc($rspayreview)) {
    echo '<!-- DEBUG CHECK 2 !-->';
    //echo $payinfo['CardholderName'];
    // other examples
}
```

There are time the debug check 2 doesnt even fire, but yet, sometimes it does and it shows me everything in the array.

For your reference, here is a var_dump example that outputs, but yet, doesn't show up in the while loop.

```
<!-- DEBUG array(7) {
  ["ResIDLink"]=>
  int(165476)
  ["PayDate"]=>
  string(26) "Mar 16 2015"
  ["CardholderName"]=>
  string(13) "xxxx"
  ["Right4CCNum"]=>
  string(4) "4984"
  ["ChargeAmount"]=>
  float(300)
  ["Paid"]=>
  int(1)
  ["CCType"]=>
  string(4) "VISA"
}
```

Does anybody have any thoughts on this? It would be GREATLY appreciated.

EDIT, as an FYI, i HAVE attempted using a `foreach`, however, it winds up giving me  `Illegal string offset` errors instead.

```
foreach( $rowpayments as $payinfo ) {
```

Comment: Why don't you `foreach` over `$rowpayments` instead of a `while` loop? Also, shouldn't it be `while($payinfo == mssql_fetch_assoc($rspayreview))` (note the double `=`)?

Comment: I have actually TRIED using for each, but all I get are  "Illegal string offset" error messages and was not sure how to fix that either. Updating question to reflect this. Thank you.

Comment: How can you get `Illegal string offset` when you `foreach($array as $key => $value)`? Keys are retrieved automatically. Also, how about the double `=` in your `while` statement? Shouldn't make it work better?

Comment: @D4V1D, a double equal in the while statement is incorrect. The is one of the few cases where the OP actually does want assignment rather than comparison

Comment: @dan08 is correct.  I have also just attempted foreach($array as $key => $value), however, am still getting the illegal string offset errors.

Comment: I think we need to see more code, like what you are doing inside the loop.

Comment: @dan08, my bad, I thought the OP wanted to make a comparison. I thinked too fast on that one :)

Comment: Thank you both for the help. :) That's just it though,  the  echo '<!-- DEBUG CHECK 2 !-->'; line isn't even firing inside the loop.   Shouldn't THAT text fire no matter what if the loop was good?

Comment: How many rows do you expect to be returned? When you call mssql_fetch_assoc, it pops the row off. So is it possible that it is empty by the time you get to the loop?

Comment: OHHHH!! I never knew that!! So because I TWO instances of mssql_fetch_assoc, the first one DOES show me the debug info, but by the time I get to the loop, it is gone! That would explain why it halfway works when I have multiple rows returned.  Geeze, sometimes it's the simplest answers.